# React axios only deleting after a page refresh

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a react express app where I'm trying to delete a post via axios (Api). However, it seems that the delete request only seems to be processed once I refresh the page and not after pressing the delete button no matter how long I wait, after observing the response from my express server. This does not happen when adding posts.

The code for my react component

```
function Home(props) {
  
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(true);

  useEffect(()=> {
    async function getPosts() {
      const allPosts = await Api.get('/posts', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem("Authorization")
        }
      })
      setPosts(allPosts.data.posts);
    }

    getPosts();

  },[trigger]);

  const onTitleChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  }

  const onDescChange = (e) => {
    setDesc(e.target.value);
  }

 const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title === "" || desc === "") {
      alert("Title and description cannot be empty");
    } else {
      await Api({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/posts/new',
        headers: {
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem("Authorization")
        },
        data: {title, user: props.id, description: desc, name: props.name}
      })
      e.target.reset();
      setShowForm(false);
      setTrigger(!trigger);
    }
  }

  const onAddButClick = () => {
    setShowForm(true);
  }

  const onDelButClick = async (e) => {
    await Api.delete(`/posts/${e.target.parentNode.dataset.postid}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("Authorization")
      }
    })
    setTrigger(!trigger);
  }

  const addBut = (<button onClick={onAddButClick}>Add Post</button>);
  const form = (<Form onSubmit={onSubmit} onDescChange={onDescChange} onTitleChange={onTitleChange}/>);
  const delBut = (<button onClick={onDelButClick}>Delete Post</button>)

  return (
    <div>
      {showForm ? form : addBut}
      {posts.map(obj=>{
        return (<div key={obj._id} data-postid={obj._id}>Title: {obj.title} desc: {obj.description} by: {obj.name}
            {obj.user == props.id ? delBut : null}
          </div>)
      })}
    </div>
  ); 
}
```

For my express server

```
router.delete('/:id', deletePost);

deletePost = [
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), 
  async (req, res, next) =>  {
    try {
     await Post.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).exec();
     res.status(200);
    } catch(err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that is related to the deletion. It may be just the data is not re-fetched / updated?

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the `onDelButClick` function?

Comment: @CyberMessiah according to my command prompt running the server, the DELETE request is only sent after I refreshed the page. When I click on the delete button multiple times, multiple requests are sent only once I refresh

Answer (score 0):

you should use return in nodejs

```
router.delete('/:id', deletePost);

deletePost = [
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), 
  async (req, res, next) =>  {
    try {
     await Post.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).exec();
     return res.status(200); // change here
    } catch(err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried this but it still does not work